# What is the difference between Nginx variables $host, $http_host, and $server_name?

Tags: nginx, rewrite

What is the difference between the three Nginx variables `$host`, `$http_host`, and `$server_name`?

I have a rewrite rule where I'm not sure which one I should be using:

```
location = /vb/showthread.php {
    # /vb/showthread.php?50271-What-s-happening&p=846039
    if ($arg_p) {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/forum/index.php?posts/$arg_p/;
        }
```

I'm looking for an answer that doesn't just say 'use ___ variable in your rewrite rule' but also explains the theoretical differences between them.

Comment: I realized later I didn't even need to specify `$scheme` and `$host`... `return 301 /forum/index.php?posts/$arg_p/;` works fine.

Comment: Most browser would work with relative URL in redirect, but the standard (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) requires absolute url in the `Location` header.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You should almost always use `$host`, as it's the only one guaranteed to have something sensible regardless of how the user-agent behaves, unless you specifically need the semantics of one of the other variables.

The difference is explained in the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html):

- `$host` contains "in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the 'Host' request header field, or the server name matching a request"
- `$http_host` contains the content of the HTTP "Host" header field, if it was present in the request
- `$server_name` contains the `server_name` of the virtual host which processed the request, as it was defined in the nginx configuration. If a `server` contains multiple `server_name`s, only the first one will be present in this variable.

Since it is legal for user-agents to send the hostname in the request line rather than in a Host: header, though it is rarely done except when connecting to proxies, you have to account for this.

You also have to account for the case where the user-agent doesn't send a hostname at all, e.g. ancient HTTP/1.0 requests and modern badly-written software. You might do so by diverting them to a catch-all virtual host which doesn't serve anything, if you are serving multiple web sites, or if you only have a single web site on your server you might process everything through a single virtual host. In the latter case you have to account for this as well.

Only the `$host` variable accounts for all the possible things that a user-agent may do when forming an HTTP request.

Comment: On the other hand, the `$server_name` is safe when `Host:` field from UA may contain arbitrary content.

Comment: Is $http_host renamed to $hostname ? I can not find such variable in Nginx doc. $hostname is the most similar one I guess.

Comment: @darkbaby123 No, it was not renamed to anything. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_).

Comment: Ah now I understand what http_<name> variable means. Thank you!

Comment: Could be `$ssl_server_name` should be mentioned also. It "returns the server name requested through SNI (1.7.0)".

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add another important point not mentioned in the accepted answer.

`$host` do **NOT** have port number, while `$http_host` does include the port number.

**edit**: not always.

I set up a header "add_header Y-blog-http_host "$http_host" always;"

Then `curl -I -L domain.com:80` (or 443) and the header doesn't show a port number at all. Verified with nginx-extra 1.10.3. Is is because it's common http(s) ports or nginx configuration? This comment just to say things do not **always** behave the way you think.

Comment: _Is is because it's common http(s) ports or nginx configuration?_ Yes, `curl` won't add the common port number to the `Host` header even if you invoke it that way. However there is no warranty that some other program will not add that number if being invoked similar way. And of course you can manually overwrite the default `Host` header using `curl -I -H 'Host: domain.com:80' ...`

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: If you don't use regular expressions in `server_name` you can ignore this answer .

Since this aspect hasn't been mentioned *at all* in other answers, but it's something that I found somewhat annoying: I use `$host` in the creation of my log file names, like so:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access_$host.log
```

Alas, if you use a regular expression in your `server_name` stanza like:

```
server_name ~^(?<subdomain>foo|bar|baz)\.example.net;
```

Your `$host` will actually end up containing the regular expression like so (yep, including the backslash and everything):

```
access_~^(?<subdomain>foo|bar|baz)\.example.net.log
```

I for one found this very annoying and ended up changing my regular expression to:

```
server_name ~^(?<fulldomain>(?<subdomain>foo|bar|baz)\.example.net);
```

to capture the full name for reuse in the log file name. The respective stanza was then changed to:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/access_$fulldomain.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this for a while. It became clear when I understood that $http_XXXXX refer to all declared header variables.

So $http_user_agent, $http_referer are "USER AGENT", "REFERER" referenced in lower case and underslash. This explained me where the hell $http_upgrade was coming from in many NGINX configuration samples.

Read it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx

Answer (score 1):

## `$http_host`

`$http_host` always equals `Host` request header field

```
Host: example.org
```

## `$host`

`$host` is in this order of precedence (from high to low):

- Host name from the request line

  ```
  GET http://example.org/test/ HTTP/1.1
  ```
- `Host` request header field
- The `server_name` (in Nginx config) matching a request, even if `server_name` is wildcard (Ex: `server_name *.example.org;`)

## `$server_name`

`$server_name` is equals to `server_name` (in Nginx config), even if `server_name` is wildcard (Ex: `server_name *.example.org;`)

### Host name from the request line

When open URL `http://host.name/test/` ...

Most browser send the request like this

```
GET /test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: host.name
```

Most browser doesn't send the request like this

```
GET http://host.name/test/ HTTP/1.1
```

Ref: [ngx_http_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host), [Nginx `$host` validation](https://steelywing.github.io/note/Note/Nginx/host/#validation)