# Manipulate .conf file to rewrite https properly

Tags: nginx, ssl, configuration, redirect

I'm having a nginx server and a domain, example.com. Each customer has his own subdomain, like wsb.example.com etc. Their content changes via PHP, but all subdomains get redirected to the same folder on the web server.

The only problem I'm having, is with accessing the domain without https. https://whatever.example.com/ works, but whatever.example.com redirects me to https://*.example.com/

What am I doing wrong?

```
server {
        listen *:80;
        listen *:443 ssl;
        server_name *.alterament.de;

        index index.php;
        root /var/www/webapp.alterament.de/public;

        ssl_certificate         ssl/alterament.de.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     ssl/alterament.de.key;

        if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
                rewrite ^/(.*) https://$server_name/$1 permanent;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /resources {
                root /var/www/webapp.alterament.de;
        }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing $server_name with $http_host in the rewrite field

Comment: It hasn't changed anything...

Answer (score 1):

You used `$server_name` in your redirect, which causes the content of the `server_name` directive to be used. This is not what you want.

Instead, [you should replace it with `$host`](https://serverfault.com/a/706439/126632).

Comment: That results in the same, no matter if I replace it with $host or $http_host.

Comment: Did you actually reload nginx?

Comment: Yes sure, the same way I reloaded nginx after commenting the ssl session, and that worked out.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration checks if the protocol is not https and force to use https:

```
if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite ^/(.*) https://$server_name/$1 permanent;
}
```

Try to comment out the whole block and restart nginx

Comment: That works, but the rewrite makes sense so is there a way to add a https without changing the domain to *.example.com?