# How to obtain hostname of request nginx

Tags: nginx

Hello I am trying to redirect all my requests to use https. I have created a server block that listens on port 80 (http) and I want to redirect the user to use `https://` however I am unsure how to obtain the hostname.

here is my server block

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name : *.example.org
    return 301 https://{{hostname}}$request_uri
}
```

I know that the URI is accessed by `$request_uri` but I am unsure how to obtain the hostname.

Do you append them by having them next to each other with no space?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/706438/126632

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link that Michael Hampton posted explains the variables in more detail but here is a direct answer.

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

You can see it work using curl and looking at the header.

http://bob.example.com to https://bob.example.com

```
[root@hm1 conf.d]# curl --head bob.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.9.13
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 02:01:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://bob.example.com/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15780000; preload
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

http://alice.example.com to https://alice.example.com

```
[root@hm1 conf.d]# curl --head alice.example.com
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.9.13
Date: Wed, 06 Apr 2016 02:01:39 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://alice.example.com/
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15780000; preload
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

Comment: you can also do `$scheme` which would change the answer to `return 301 $scheme://$host$request_uri;`