# Nginx HTTPS configuration redirects to faulty URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I have Nginx working with gunicorn as an upstream server.
I am trying to configure the site to use HTTPS and force all HTTP requests to use SSL.

Here is my nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf`:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    _;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}



server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  _;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/nginx/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/nginx/private.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

After installing this config whenever I go to:
`https://example.com/page.html` then it returns the page as expected.

But when I use: `https://example.com/` then the browser weirdly redirects to: `https: //_/`

This problem also happens when I use the the HTTP version of the site at
`www.example.com`

How can I rewrite the above configuration to make it work properly?

Comment: There are mistakes in your configuration other than the one you asked about; read [Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) carefully to learn about and correct these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration specifically states that HTTP requests should be redirected to `https://_/`.

```
       server_name    _;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

Because `server_name` is set to `_`, that is what is used for `$server_name`.

[The variable you should be using](https://serverfault.com/a/706439/126632) instead of `$server_name` is `$host`. This will always have something sensible based on what the browser requested (provided the browser requested something sensible).

Ideally, though, a `server` block with `server_name _;` shouldn't serve anything other than an error page. Rather, you should have `server` blocks for your actual domain names. Such a configuration prevents unintended access to your server via plain IP address or hostnames that aren't configured in nginx or your web application.

Comment: I replaced _ with example.com and www.example.com and it worked.

Comment: However, using `$host` is less secure because you're allowing a permanent redirect based on what the browser provides.  This is a great start to a XSS attack.