# What is the $server_name variable set to?

Tags: nginx

I have a server block to redirect all http requests to https as follows:

```
server {
   listen 0.0.0.0:80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name a.com b.com c.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

It seems that requests coming in using all three domain names on port 80 will be redirected to https://a.com. Is this how `$server_name` is set?

Comment: You probably want to use `$host` instead of `$server_name`. See [What is the difference between Nginx variables $host, $http_host, and $server_name?](https://serverfault.com/q/706438/126632)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

> The first name becomes the primary server name.

You can use three separate `server` blocks, or Michael Hampton's excellent suggestion of the `$host` variable instead.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_server_name which was vague.

Comment: `server_name_in_redirect` won't help here, and it's off by default anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yeah, your `$host` thing is much better.