# nginx-1.15.9 Variable support in "ssl_certificate" and "ssl_certificate_key" directives

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https

So [nginx-1.15.9](https://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-announce/2019/000231.html) was released very recently with the following change:

> Feature: variables support in the "ssl_certificate" and
>          "ssl_certificate_key" directives.

I setup an instance with multiple domains pointing to the following server block. I am using [dehydrated](https://github.com/lukas2511/dehydrated) to generate the certs automatically and in their own respective folders.

However, despite trying several variations and googling for various solutions, I am not having any success in having the variables in the "ssl_certificate" and "ssl_certificate_key" directives being recognised.

- Have verified that the certs are generated correctly (with fullchain.pem and privkey.pem)
- The error I'm getting from navigating to the https URL directly: Secure Connection Failed
- https works perfectly if I update the "$server_name" to the actual domain folder containing the certs

Appreciate if someone could take a look at my server block to identify what I'm doing wrong or point me in the correct direction. Thank you.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    # ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/dehydrated/certs/$server_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/dehydrated/certs/$server_name/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: Ah I should have thought of checking the error log to see the output. The error is it not being able to load the certificate. $server_name simply outputs a blank. I just can't figure out what $variable to specify the current domain. I've already tried $uri and $hostname, both not giving the desired output.

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://serverfault.com/a/706439/126632).

Comment: Thanks for the link Michael. I'm actually referring to this [list](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables) but I've tried $host, $server_name, $http_host to no avail. Am I not understanding them correctly but I can't seem to find the $variable to specify the actual current domain name being served.

Comment: `$host` should be it. I wouldn't expect `$server_name` to be useful, since you aren't likely to have a certificate named `_`. Maybe this feature doesn't actually work yet?

Comment: This person [managed to get it to work](https://jeremyfelt.com/2019/02/28/variable-ssl-certificate-directives-in-nginx/) and he used $server_name. I tried reaching out to him but couldn't get a reply so I assume he does not want to be bothered.

Comment: I notice that [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) uses `$ssl_server_name` which may be available earlier in the handshake.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using `$ssl_server_name` instead of `$server_name` and that Nginx has read-access to your certificates.

I've made a [full write up using LetsEncrypt](https://oky.dk/blog/nginx-ssl-variables). In your case it would look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    # ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/dehydrated/certs/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/dehydrated/certs/$ssl_server_name/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the only variable name that is supported?

Comment: I believe there is more, but it's the only one I've been able to get dynamically.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It tells it cannot find the file.