# Auto Virtual Host - Single Nginx config

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

I am trying to create a single Nginx config for multiple hosts based on a directory. I followed a guide which seems to work well with standard HTTP setup but when I add the HTTPS 301 redirect, I can an error "invalid redirect". Any ideas on this? Below is my config. Tx

```
server {
  listen x.x.x.x:80;

  server_name ~^(?<sname>.+?).domain.com$;

  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen x.x.x.x:443 ssl default_server;
    server_name ~^(?<sname>.+?).domain.com$;


root /var/web/$sname;

index index.html index.htm index.php;


charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }


ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wildcard.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wildcard.domain.com/privkey.pem;

access_log /var/log/nginx/$sname-access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/wildcard-error.log debug;

error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

        location ~ \.php {
                include fastcgi.conf;
                #fastcgi_index index.php;
                include cors_support;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        }
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
  location /.well-known {
    root /var/www/html;
  }
}
```

Comment: In my Personal mind would it be more Sufficient and easier to manage, to not have a single file Installation, instead I wrote my pages in each file which only contains the same domain, and I mean I read already that is maybe nearly impossible what you are trying, but however i am unsure about this part but oyu dont tell any logs

Comment: What is the output of `curl -v http://test.domain.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect is "invalid" because you are trying to redirect to `https://~^(?<sname>.+?).domain.com$` which is pretty obviously invalid.

Why is this so?

You chose to write your redirect as follows:

```
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

This doesn't make sense. The `server_name` is not a valid hostname.

Instead, you should redirect to the same host that the user agent used. The [correct variable](https://serverfault.com/q/706438/126632) to use there is `$host`, not `$server_name`.

```
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Comment: Michael, you are Stalking ME :-) However, and also a Good Solutin additonal might be: https://serverfault.com/questions/706438/what-is-the-difference-between-nginx-variables-host-http-host-and-server-na?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @djdomi That is the link in the answer!

Comment: point to you didn't see that there was a link to the same site ;) and if I get an uovote on time each we meet us in the same topic I would very fast upto 500 points xD

Comment: Thanks the solution @MichaelHampton worked.  What does $host actually equate to in this scenario?

Comment: @WallyKaye That's explained in the linked post.